# Connecting computers

Tags: ethernet, network-shares, home-networking

Have a switch with internet connection. To this switch are connected two computers. And also wi-fi router. To router is then connected another computer. What is the best way to connect two computers connected directly to switch with computer connected to router? All connections are established using ethernet cables. Would like to transfer files (etc.) between these three computers.

Additional info (Wi-fi Router):
Operation mode is Wireless Router. It can be changed to Access point, WISP and Range Extender.
Connection type is Dynamic IP. It can be changed to Static IP, PPPoE, L2TP, PPTP and BigPond Cable.

Can add more details if needed.

[image: Network schema]

Comment: Generally for Windows, turn ON Network Discovery, File and Print Sharing, Password Protected Sharing and restart if necessary. Connections are Ethernet so Public / Private is not an issue. Map a folder T: \\othercomputerIP\folder  and connect.  This is basic file sharing that has worked fine since XP.  May need some fine tuning.

Comment: I get the feeling this 'extra' router is set to do NAT/DHCP… we need more info. What doesn't work at the moment, what subnet is everything on?

Comment: A network schema showing all elements would help.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Just added network schema (to original post).